# Excel-vba: Conditional Formatting: Cell Style

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the `.style` function in this formatting, but vba doesn't want to use it.  Am I just using the `.style` wrong or do I need to use a different method to color the cells?

```
'Conditional Formatting
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.Add xlErrorsCondition, Formula1:= _
    "=IF(" & Cells(SelectedGroup, AreaSelected(2)).Offset(2, 1) & "=""Not Used"",TRUE, _ 
    FALSE)"
.FormatConditions(1).Style = "Bad"

.FormatConditions.Add xlErrorsCondition, Formula1:= _ 
    "=IF(" & Cells(SelectedGroup, AreaSelected(2)).Offset(2, 1) & "=""Used"",TRUE,FALSE)"
.FormatConditions(1).Style = "Good"
```

Comment: According to this, style isn't a method for formatcondition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatcondition-object-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style is a property of the Range object. In order to use it, you need to end your With statement and apply the style to the Range itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-style-property-excel